# Docker exits the first command and then starts the next command , does not run both commands parallelly

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am running a docker file which will do two operations -

1. Install an application (written docker commands)
2. Deploy some files in the application server ( separate script : deploy.sh)

I am writing the docker CMD like this at the end of the docker file-

```
CMD /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start && ./deploy.sh  && tail -f /dev/null
```

The script deploy.sh has the executable commands to execute the deployment in the installed application .

But I see that when the deploy.sh starts running the installed application abruptly stops which indicates that the first command has stopped running.

How can I make both run parallelly ?

Comment: try putting the command in a script. e.g. `entrypoint.sh` and set the CMD only to the entrypoint.sh

Comment: It looks like your container doesn't do anything; it runs some setup scripts and then runs `tail` forever?  Can you do the "deploy" step either in a Dockerfile `RUN` command or an entrypoint wrapper script, then run the application itself in the foreground (without an init script or the artificial `tail`)?

Comment: @ckaserer I tried this - CMD ./entrypoint.sh 
And in the entrypoint.sh I have written the commands - #!/bin/bash
/etc/init.d/MarkLogic start && ./deploytde.sh && tail -f /dev/null . But it gives me same error .

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried this in the dockerfile -  
 RUN /bin/bash entrypoint.sh
CMD /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start
But it gives me this error - executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /bin/bash entrypoint.sh]: exit code: 1 though it runs the entrypoint.sh script and after running it gives me same issue which is- it exits the first command as soon the second starts.